# I got the code to print a random value from a column in csv except it works sometimes, and sometimes it does not

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class FileVersion2_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String line = "";
        String splitBy = ",";
        int counter = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("C:\\Users\\myfile.csv"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                counter++;
                int min = 0;
                int max = 151;
                int random_int = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                if (counter == random_int) {
                    String[] file = line.split(splitBy);
                    System.out.println(file[0]);
                }
            }
        } catch (

        IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I press run, sometimes it prints out one value from the column, sometimes the line comes out blank, and sometimes comes out with 3 different values from the same column. Could someone explain why this is happening? Is my Math.random a flawed way to go?

Comment: The thing is that you get a random number. And then check if it is equal with `counter` you have. Of course, sometimes it will print one value or many values or none. If I understood well what your issue is. Check your logic and what you want to achieve. Good luck

Comment: How many columns are in your file?  You know that a column with `"A,B,C"` in it will look like 3 columns not 1...  Do you really have 151 columns in your CSV??

Comment: oh the counter is for the rows that it's counting down from, and file[0] is the location of the column. i realized if i used if counter == # it will print from that row, but i tried to make it a randomized row. lol

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are re-generating your random integer for every line in the file. Therefore there is no guarantee that `counter == random_int` will ever be true, or only be true once.

What you should be doing instead is generating your random number before the while loop.